# Excel VBA Macro to Display Message at a specific time

Tags: vba, excel

Really simple question here, can someone tell me why my code to display a message in the morning doesn't work? Can't see why its not working should be so simple!

```
Sub SetAlarm()
    Application.OnTime TimeValue"09:30:00", "DisplayAlarm"
End Sub

Sub DisplayAlarm()
    MsgBox "Good Morning"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions below ? if they worked please give a proper feedback, and mark one of them as "ANSWER" (by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of their post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `Sub SetAlarm` in `Workbook_Open()` event (please find code below). That way sub will automatically trigger when you open your Workbook. In order to trigger `Sub DisplayAlarm`, your Workbook needs to be open at a specified time.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime "09:30:00", "DisplayAlarm"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, will this only work when I open excel at the beginning of the day? Ideally i want the code to work whether I have opened excel in the morning or left it running all night. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. as long as Workbook is open, it will trigger every day at specified time, in this case at 9:30AM. So it doesn't matter if you open it in the morning or late evening.

Comment: Sorry but this code simply doesn't work, I really don't know why ,its so frustrating! Can you have a look?       
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime "09:30:00", "DisplayAlarm"
End Sub

Sub DisplayAlarm()
    MsgBox "Good Morning"
End Sub

Comment: Did you put Private Sub Workbook_open() in ThisWorkbook module? If you put it in regular Module (like Module1), it will not work. And after you put Private Sub Workbook_open() in right place, you have to reopen workbook in order to start macro.

Answer (score 3):

To change as little as possible of your current code, you need run your `Sub SetAlarm` somehow.

So Either have a Button placed in one of the sheets, and assign the `Sub SetAlarm` to it. Or, you can use the code below, and add it when you open the Workbook (as long as it's before 9:30:00 AM).

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SetAlarm    
End Sub
```